# Iterate over two-dimensional Vector of Options

Tags: rust

I try to print a two-dimensional vector of options for debugging purpose:

```
type Board = Vec<Vec<Option<String>>>;
let board: Board = vec![vec![None; 100]; 100];
for row in board.iter() {
    for field in row.iter() {
        match field {
            Some(val) => print!("{}", val),
            None => print!(" ")
        }
    }
    println!("");
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error: type mismatch resolving `<core::slice::Iter<'_, core::option::Option<String>> as
                                core::iter::Iterator>::Item == core::option::Option<_>`:
 expected &-ptr,
    found enum `core::option::Option` [E0271]
```

It seems somehow `iter()` does not return what I believe to be an iterator, but I am not sure what to make out of that error message. I tried variations of `iter_mut`, references, `ref`s, mutable references.

Comment: FWIW, it's probably idiomatic to do `for row in &board { for field in row { ... }}`, without calling `iter`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The iterator returned by `Vec::iter` yields references, not the values themselves, i.e. in your case `&Option<String>` instead of `Option<String>`. You will have to dereference the values you get from the iterator, as follows:

```
match *field {
    Some(ref val) => print!("{}", val),
    None => print!(" ")
}
```

Note that you also need to use `ref` in the `Some` arm of the pattern match, to avoid moving `val`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Is my code not idiomatic or is this really the correct way to do it?

Comment: @Kreisquadratur: If it's for debugging purposes, then `println!("{:?}", board);` would work by itself. I believe there is also the possibility to ask for fancier formatting in Debug printing.

Comment: @matthieu-m Right, my snippet is indeed from `impl fmt::Debug for GameState` which is a struct holding Board. I just wanted (i) learn how to write your own Debug implementation and (ii) was not happy about the default output.

Comment: @Kreisquadratur Yeah, I think your code is fine. Is there something in particular that you don't like about it?

Comment: @fjh I guess the "dislike" is a discrepancy of beginner's expected and actual syntax + application. Three examples: (i) When do I use `&` vs `ref`; couldn't `ref` be replaced by `&` and does "the right thing"(tm) case by case? (ii) why can `Println!("{}", foo)` infer that I actually need `Println!("{}", *foo)` but `match` can't/won't? (iii) Why does `iter()` exist if I can omit it?

Comment: For (ii): `println!` and `write!` macros have are specifically make to work with references (macros have the flexibility to do this). Pretty much everything else in the language needs to specify between references and values.

Comment: For (iii): the for loop takes a value that has an implementation of the [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) trait. There's generally two ways to work with iterators: for loops and function chaining. `iter()` is used for function chaining.

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson @Kreisquadratur re iii) `iter()` is needed wherever you need to pass in a value that implements `Iterator`. You can omit it when the value is expected to implement `IntoIterator` (like in for loops).

Comment: @Kreisquadratur Re (i): [this](http://rustbyexample.com/scope/borrow/ref.html) might be useful to you. I don't think `ref` could be replaced by `&` in general. The distinction isn't that intuitive at first, but it will start making sense when you have used it a few times.

Comment: Dang, I had it wrong, thanks. There really needs to a beginner explanation of how the traits in `std::iter` work together.

Comment: @jfh Thanks both of you. One can't read *Docs* and *ByExample* often enough :-/