# Rust 2D sub-window iterator

Tags: matrix, rust, iterator

I am using a `Vec` to store a 2D (row major) matrix of values. I would like to iterate over this matrix with a sliding 2D sub-window to apply a filter (which is unfortunately non-separable).

I have seen in the slice documentation that a `windows` function exists, which is what I want but in 2 dimensions.

I thought about implementing this as:

```
fn main() {
    // 4 rows 3 columns
    let dim: (usize, usize) = (4, 3);
    // Place-holder matrix
    #[rustfmt::skip]
    let mat = vec![0,  1,  2,
                   3,  4,  5,
                   6,  7,  8,
                   9, 10, 11];

    // 2D index to 1D index
    let linearize = |r, c| r * dim.1 + c;
    // The dimensions of my sub-window
    let win_size: usize = 2;
    // Calculate the bounds for which the top left corner of each window may exist
    let bounds: (usize, usize) = (dim.0 - win_size + 1, dim.1 - win_size + 1);
    // Convert window 1D index into a 2D index
    let split = |i| (i / win_size, i % win_size);

    // Iterate over all the top left corners
    let window_2d = (0..bounds.0 * bounds.1).map(|i| {
        // Get the 2D index of the top left corner
        let (r, c) = (i / bounds.1, i % bounds.1);
        // Borrow the matrix, so our closure may own the reference
        let bmat = &mat;
        // Return an iterator for this window
        return (0..win_size * win_size).map(move |x| {
            let (wr, wc) = split(x);
            return bmat[linearize(wr + r, wc + c)];
        });
    });

    // Print the windows out
    window_2d.for_each(|it| {
        print!("[ ");
        it.for_each(|x| print!("{} ", x));
        println!("]");
    });
}
```

Essentially creating an iterator over a range of indices and then mapping to the square bracket operator of the matrix. 
As far as I know, this is going to have the overhead of a bounds check for each deref of the iterator.

I'm wondering if there's an alternative which would elide the bounds checks? Maybe using a combination of `chunks`, `windows` and `zip`, to chunk the matrix into rows, each with a sliding window, then zip the row's windows and flatten the result?

Thanks!

**Edit**:
I'm not looking to simply iterate over a 2D array, I want to slide a 2D window over the array, similar to how the `std::slice::windows` function works.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I return an iterator over a 2D array with the enumeration indices included?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52339851/155423); [The best way to iterate over sections of 2D arrays in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43293834/155423); [How can I iterate over a 2D vector in functional style?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48852454/155423)...

Comment: ... [Iterate over two-dimensional Vector of Options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32619964/155423); [Rust efficiently chunk large vector into a vector of vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54414210/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for your response, I have edited the question. None of your linked questions actually answers my question. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293834/the-best-way-to-iterate-over-sections-of-2d-arrays-in-rust) which you linked is close, but remains unanswered and I believe that my question has a better illustration of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've got for now is wrapping the matrix access in an unsafe block to elide the bounds check.

With some other misc changes, this is the full example now:

```
fn split_factory(cols: usize) -> impl Fn(usize) -> (usize, usize) {
    // Declaring that cols must be positive allows more aggressive optimisation of div and mod.
    if cols < 1 {
        unreachable!()
    }
    move |i| (i / cols, i % cols)
}

fn main() {
    // 4 rows 3 columns
    let dim: (usize, usize) = (4, 3);
    // Place-holder matrix
    #[rustfmt::skip]
    let mat = vec![0,  1,  2,
                   3,  4,  5,
                   6,  7,  8,
                   9, 10, 11];

    // The dimensions of my sub-window
    let win_dim = (3usize, 2usize);
    // Calculate the bounds for which the top left corner of each window may exist
    let bounds = (dim.0 - win_dim.0 + 1, dim.1 - win_dim.1 + 1);
    // Iterate over all the top left corners
    let convolution_iter = (0..bounds.0 * bounds.1)
        .map(split_factory(bounds.1))
        .map(|(r, c)| {
            // Borrow the matrix, so our closure may own the reference
            let bmat = &mat;
            // Return an iterator for this window
            return (0..win_dim.0 * win_dim.1)
                .map(split_factory(win_dim.1))
                .map(move |(wr, wc)| {
                    let px = (wr + r) * dim.1 + (wc + c);
                    (px, unsafe { *bmat.get_unchecked(px) })
                });
        });

    // Print the windows out (badly...)
    convolution_iter.for_each(|it| println!("{:?}", it.collect::<Vec<(usize, i32)>>()));
}
```

Would still be nicer to avoid `unsafe` and the indirection of looking up the matrix with indices.